# Scipy runtime warning

Tags: python, scipy

I am using `ndimage` to fill a number of shapes (in detail, I use the commands `ndimage.binary_fill_holes`, `ndimage.label`, `ndimage.sum` and `ndimage.center_of_mass`). When I run the code, I get the following warning:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/
 python/scipy/ndimage/measurements.py:1163: RuntimeWarning: invalid 
 value encountered in divide
results = [sum(input * grids[dir].astype(float), labels, index) / 
 normalizer for dir in range(input.ndim)]
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the code (simplified, if applicable) where you define the variables in the results equation? So that others are able reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error only when you have a `0/0` or an `inf/inf` division.

This means that in at least one case of the `for` loop within the list comprehension, your variable `normalizer` AND at the same time the return value of `sum()` are both `0` or both `+/-inf`.

The piece of code generating the error belongs to `center_of_mass(input, labels=None, index=None)` ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/ndimage/measurements.py#L1225)).

How are you calling `center_of_mass()`?

One possibility if that you did not specify `label` and `index`. In that case the variable `normalizer` can be zero only if the input array has zero mean. In that case, can you check the value of `input.sum()` before the call? One trivial possibility is that the input is an array of zeros. In that case you get a `0/0`.

If you're providing `label` and `index`, there is in any case something wrong with the input before the call to `center_of_mass()`.

If you don't know what/where is the problem, try printing some data. The result of this type of error is a `nan` value: `center_of_mass()` will return a tuple like `(nan, nan)`.

Comment: The warning was due to an error in `ndimage.center_of_mass`: I called it using `blob_CM = ndimage.center_of_mass(mask_2_filled, label_im, range(nb_labels + 1))`. The correct form is `blob_CM = ndimage.center_of_mass(mask_2_filled, label_im, label_center)`. I took the syntax from [here](http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/pylect/advanced/image_processing/index.html#id14).